# Switch NavigationItem title with segmented control

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol, uinavigationitem

I have one navigationitem and one navigationbar. The navigation item has the title (and button) and navigationbar (below the navigationitem) has a segmented control.

**How do I make it so the title changes on the navigationitem when one side of the segmented control is pressed (objective-c)?**

Here's the code from the .m file

```
   if (segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
            UIWebView *webview6=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
     NSString *url6=@"http://apple.com";
        NSURL *nsurl6=[NSURL URLWithString:url6];
            NSURLRequest *nsrequest6=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl6];
        [webview6 loadRequest:nsrequest6];
 webview6.scrollView.bounces = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:webview6];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront: navbar2];
    }
    if (segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
       UIWebView *webview7=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
         NSString *url7=@"http://yahoo.com";
        NSURL *nsurl7=[NSURL URLWithString:url7];
            NSURLRequest *nsrequest7=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl7];
        [webview7 loadRequest:nsrequest7];
        webview7.scrollView.bounces = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:webview7];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront: navbar2];
        }
```

Here's what it looks like -

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `self.navigationItem.title` to set the title.

Comment: You should write this as a solution, not as a question.

Comment: No, but please write a solution in the Answers and questions in the Comments